# Python lookup hostname from IP with 1 second timeout

Tags: python, dns, hostname, nameservers

How can I look up a hostname given an IP address?  Furthermore, how can I specify a timeout in case no such reverse DNS entry exists?  Trying to keep things as fast as possible.  Or is there a better way?  Thank you!

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr("69.59.196.211")
('stackoverflow.com', ['211.196.59.69.in-addr.arpa'], ['69.59.196.211'])
```

For implementing the timeout on the function, [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-python-function-call) has answers on that.

Comment: what about something like 'http:/1.0.1.0/blah/blahm.html' ?

Comment: @Eiyrioü von Kauyf: That was not the question asked (return a hostname when specified an ip address).

Comment: it's the same question - however i'm asking do you have a suggested way to normalize that and do socket.gethostbyaddr("1.0.1.0") or the like? It's the same question but the input format is different - gethostbyaddr does not like non normalized input.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf yes because its excactly what the method is supposed to do: ip to dns conversion...
you could use a regex for that like `http(|s)://([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/.*`. there are plenty more out there, which are better or more precisious

Comment: Does not work for mapped ipv4: ----> 1 socket.gethostbyaddr('::ffff:69.59.196.211')

error: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: socket has its own method to set a timeout: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout

Comment: ('apps2.ideal-logic.com', [], ['69.59.196.211']) . this is the format of output I get when I above code. The possibility might be the ip has been changed. But I  am getting such result for all my domains too like for one of my domain when passed its ip showing something like this  `('ip-149-202-166.eu', [], ['149.202.166.163'])`

Comment: Does this handle ipv6 addresses or only ipv4?

Answer (score 22):

What you're trying to accomplish is called Reverse DNS lookup.

```
socket.gethostbyaddr("IP") 
# => (hostname, alias-list, IP)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html?highlight=gethostbyaddr#socket.gethostbyaddr

However, for the timeout part I have read about people running into problems with this. I would check out [PyDNS](http://pydns.sourceforge.net/) or [this](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/asynchronous-dns-resolution) solution for more advanced treatment.