# Reverse dns lookup with scapy in python

Tags: python, scapy, reverse-dns

How can I do reverse DNS lookup using `scapy` in Python? I look for it in Google but I couldn't find related to this topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python lookup hostname from IP with 1 second timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575760/python-lookup-hostname-from-ip-with-1-second-timeout)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok. I have found my answerm and I want to share it in here, because someone could look for same thing.
One line of code is enough to make a reverse dns query in scapy, which is:

```
sr1(IP(dst="8.8.8.8")/UDP()/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname="211.196.59.69.in-addr.arpa", qtype='PTR')))
```

Answer (score 10):

Reverse DNS is already written into Python's Socket module. Simply use the following:

```
 >>> import socket
 >>> socket.gethostbyaddr("69.59.196.211")
 ('stackoverflow.com', ['211.196.59.69.in-addr.arpa'], ['69.59.196.211'])
```

Which was originally posted here, [Python lookup hostname from IP with 1 second timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575760/python-lookup-hostname-from-ip-with-1-second-timeout), by https://stackoverflow.com/users/81179/christophed

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. How can I do this operaton using scapy in python?

Comment: You should still be able to import the `socket` module and use `socket.gethostbyaddr` while in Scapy.

Comment: I also doesn't work very well for my case. I generally get the answer 'unknown host'