# how to get readable rdata with scapy

Tags: scapy

hello i try to do a reverse dns with scapy
this is the command

```
ans=sr1(IP(dst="8.8.8.8")/UDP(dport=53)/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname="36.210.58.216.in-addr.arpa",qtype=6)),verbose=0)
```

this is the rdata section

```
 <DNSRR  rrname='210.58.216.in-addr.arpa.' type=SOA rclass=IN ttl=59 rdata='\x03ns2\x06google\x03com\x00\tdns-admin\xc0<\x05\xfeY\xa9\x00\x00\x03\x84\x00\x00\x03\x84\x00\x00\x07\x08\x00\x00\x00<' |>
```

now in rdata i can see its ns2.google.com , but how i can get it in normal way?
and/or how can i resolve the rest of the enswer (the admin part)

p.s how exactly shuld i use at dyndns_add() ? (with the packet from above )

Answer (score 0):

Dissection of rdata field is not implemented in scapy. You can add your own dissector, but there is no built-in way you could convert the value into structured form in default scapy without additional code.

If the questions is about extending scapy with new protocols, then it is answered elsewhere.

Comment: i am try to get the real server from an ip

Comment: (reverse dns , how do i do it?)

Comment: On reverse DNS in scapy look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979250/reverse-dns-lookup-with-scapy-in-python