# socket.gethostbyaddr returning unexpected results

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

So I tried to get a host name from an IP address following [**this example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575760/python-lookup-hostname-from-ip-with-1-second-timeout)

Thus, I wrote up this little snippet of code trying to reproduce their results

```
import socket

print(socket.gethostbyaddr('69.59.196.211'))
```

Yet the output to this particular piece of code is the following:

```
('peak-colo-196-211.peak.org', [], ['69.59.196.211'])
```

I'm completely at a loss as to why I'm not receiving the proper host name (or at least **stackoverflow.com** like in the example)

I'm certain I'm missing something exceptionally silly, but I've had difficulty finding an answer. I recognize that the provided example is old, but I get similarly crude/cryptic results no matter what I try. If someone could explain this to me I'd be extremely appreciative.

Comment: Why do you think it should give `stackoverflow.com`? `[i[-1][0] for i in socket.getaddrinfo("stackoverflow.com", 0)]` gives `['104.16.33.249', '104.16.34.249', '104.16.36.249', '104.16.35.249', '104.16.37.249']`, none of them is your IP...

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, I suppose that the IP address they use might have changed in the last nearly 6 years...

Comment: None of those IPs returned stackoverflow for me either. But it's not just SO or the example IP, I get these really crude results for anything I try

Comment: @Berry Any solution for the problem found I am getting similar response from the function call to get the hostname from the ipaddress passed

Comment: Unfortunately no :(