# How can I get the REMOTE host name with python?

Tags: python, networking, localhost, ip

Im building an application that contacts with local hosts, instead of asking or showing the IP address and letting the user to interact with the ip, I wanted to show the device name directly.

Is there any way to do that?

I only could do that with other applications but not with python.

I searched in socket and in many other modules but I did not find the solution, maybe is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Given an IP address the function `socket.gethostbyaddr()` returns a tuple containing:

- Host Name
- Alias list for the IP address if any
- IP address of the host

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyaddr

Answer (score -1):

That should be possible as following:

```py
import socket
socket.gethostbyaddr("69.59.196.211")
```

resource: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2575779/20443541

Comment: Don't answer a question simply with a link to another Stack Overflow question or answer. If an answer to another question solves the asker's problem, then the question is a duplicate and should be flagged as such. Use the `Flag` link under the question's text and look for the "Duplicate" option.

Comment: Well then it is a dublicate. I still think providing the answer, even if it is a dublicate should be valid.

Comment: From [How Do I Write a Good Answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help], *`Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which... have already been asked and answered many times before.`* Please also read [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370).